# Azure Storage CORS configuration

Tags: azure, cors, vps

How can I configure azure storage CORS without programmatically ? Do I really need to install visual studio and configure myself.
My current situation right now is I'm created linux instance VPS in Digital Ocean. I'm running wordpress web application and integrated with azure CDN.

I'm getting http origin not allows from the font file, I knew that something deal with CORS from azure storage. How can I configure the best way ?

Answer (score 1):

CORS configuration is configurable via REST API's - so not bound to VS at all. If you are running Linux you can configure using Java or Node.Js. Resources:
- CORS overview with pointers to REST docs http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx 
- Java client library - https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java
- Node client library - https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node